# Responsive designed bootstrap - stacking of nested columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a problem with Twitter Bootstrap:

I'm trying to do a responsive layout, and I have a 2 columns fluid row with a 2 nested columns in each column (first example in an image).

When I try to resize the browser to pretend it is a smaller-screened device, at some resolutions nested columns are stacked vertically (second example in the image), even though
there is enough room for those nested columns to be placed horizontally, and not vertically (third example in an image).

What should I do to prevent nested columns from vertical stacking, when there is enough space for them to place them horizontally?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/425/).

and image is as following[image]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        6
        <ul class="row-fluid">
            <li class="span6">
                3
            </li>
            <li class="span6">
                3
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        6
                    <ul class="row-fluid">
            <li class="span6">
                3
            </li>
            <li class="span6">
                3
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

​

I didn't find any solution for this problem, so I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: What browser(s)/OS are did you take your screen shots in?

Comment: Also, is there a reason for using `<ul>`/`<li>`s (if it were me, I'd go for `<div>`)? Another thing that jumps out at me is the last `</diV>` (you should probably make that a lower-case "v"). A quick version edit [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MgcDU/423/show/light/), though, I'm not sure if that fixes anything.

Comment: Chrome, Firefox and Opera give same results. I'm working on windows 7.
I'm sorry for this diV. Generally I've tried different configs, as far as I know ul/li are a little bit different in bootstrap, but I've tried with standart divs and gave me the same result.

Comment: On my mac Mountain Lion, the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Opera appear to behave as expected. I'm not seeing what you're seeing in those screen shots (visually, it looks like you're getting columns, then 100% fluid, then columns again as you go down in size... Is that correct?). Looks like the scaffolding of [Twitter's Bootstrap is setup to break to fluid-width columns around 700-ish pixel width](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) (that's what I'm seeing with the [demo you posted](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MgcDU/418/show/light/)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure if understand you correctly, and I'm afraid that maybe I misexplain what I want to do. At my computer somewhere around 767px px bootstrap stacks blue columns vertically and that is ok. But at 767px and lower red columns are stacked vertically and I want those red columns inside a single blue column to be positioned horizontally, while down to 480px there is enough space for them to be placed one next to the other one, and at the lower resolution than 480px stack everything vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved the problem. For those resolutions I had a problem I've changed li to float: left and width to 49%. Like this:

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
}
```

Probably there should be some way to do this without changing bootstrap/or hardcoding.

Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update. It was hard for me to help because I was not seeing the problems you described. Anyway, glad you got it fixed! :)